# Is there any way to suggest to ConTeXt to take advantage of multiple cores?

Tags: luatex, context, performance

I have access to a relatively slow, but hugely (12) multi-cored machine. My 200+ page document has compile times in the 400 second range. Are there any flags or hints that I can give to the mtx-context engine (or better engine flag?) to improve performance of some steps?

The output it currently gives is:

```
mtx-context     | warning: no (local) file './trapBookProduct', proceeding
mtx-context     | redirect texlua -> luajittex: luajittex --luaonly "/opt/context/tex/texmf-linux-64/bin/mtxrun" --script context --arrange --batchmode --noconsole --path=/home/ubuntu/ConTeXt/img trapBookProduct --redirected
mtx-context     | warning: no (local) file './trapBookProduct', proceeding
mtx-context     | run 1: luajittex --fmt="/opt/context/tex/texmf-cache/luatex-cache/context/5fe67e0bfe781ce0dde776fb1556f32e/formats/luajittex/cont-en" --interaction="batchmode" --jobname="trapBookProduct" --lua="/opt/context/tex/texmf-cache/luatex-cache/context/5fe67e0bfe781ce0dde776fb1556f32e/formats/luajittex/cont-en.lui" --no-parse-first-line --c:arrange --c:batchmode --c:currentrun=1 --c:directives="logs.target=file" --c:engine="luajittex" --c:fulljobname="./trapBookProduct" --c:input="./trapBookProduct" --c:kindofrun=1 --c:maxnofruns=9 --c:noarrange --c:noconsole --c:path="/home/ubuntu/ConTeXt/img" --c:redirected "cont-yes.mkiv"
This is LuajitTeX, Version beta-0.85.0 (TeX Live 2016/dev) (rev 5550) 
 system commands enabled.

mtx-context     | arrange run: luajittex --fmt="/opt/context/tex/texmf-cache/luatex-cache/context/5fe67e0bfe781ce0dde776fb1556f32e/formats/luajittex/cont-en" --interaction="batchmode" --jobname="trapBookProduct" --lua="/opt/context/tex/texmf-cache/luatex-cache/context/5fe67e0bfe781ce0dde776fb1556f32e/formats/luajittex/cont-en.lui" --no-parse-first-line --c:arrange --c:batchmode --c:currentrun=2 --c:directives="logs.target=file" --c:engine="luajittex" --c:final --c:fulljobname="./trapBookProduct" --c:input="./trapBookProduct" --c:kindofrun=3 --c:maxnofruns=9 --c:noconsole --c:path="/home/ubuntu/ConTeXt/img" --c:redirected "cont-yes.mkiv"This is LuajitTeX, Version beta-0.85.0 (TeX Live 2016/dev) (rev 5550) 
 system commands enabled.

system          | total runtime: 180.058 seconds
```

Including the flag:

> % engine=luajittex

Did improve compile times by about 200 seconds, but are there any other mechanisms to use?

Comment: Some years ago, Taco Hoekwater, one of the main developers of luatex, wrote this on the context mailing list: "typesetting (currently) is a single-process streaming task, and that is not easily fixed at all." So for the time being, the answer to your question is "no."